# Appropriateness of calculating scale means based on available non-missing responses (i.e., person-mean imputation)

Tags: scales, missing-data

This question came up in a consulting context, and I was interested in your thoughts.

#### Context

One strategy for dealing with occasional missing data when calculating scale means looks like this in the language of SPSS:

```
COMPUTE depmean =  mean.4(dep1, dep2, dep3, dep4, dep5, dep6).
EXECUTE.
```

I.e., calculate the mean of a psychological scale such as depression by taking the mean of six items. 
If a participant has four or more non-missing items, return the mean of the non-missing items. 
If the participant has three or fewer non-missing items, return missing.

Of course the number of items in the scale and the threshold number items for calculating the mean can vary.

#### Question

- In general, under what conditions, would you see this method of dealing with missing data to be appropriate?
- If you perceive it to be inappropriate, what alternative procedure would you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some years ago, I thought it might be a good idea to apply person-mean imputation (person-mean substitution or case-mean imputation) in case of item non-response. Nowadays, however, it seems obvious to me that this approach assumes that all scale items share similar characteristics (similar variance, standard deviation, item difficulty, etc.). In other words, I would be concerned if some respondents do not answer difficult/sensitive/... items.

[Bono et al (2007: 7)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S155174110600043X) are less concerned about this approach:

> "Person-mean imputation requires
>   substitution of the mean of all of an
>   individual’s completed items for those
>   items that were not completed on a
>   given scale. This differs from
>   item-mean where the mean response of
>   the whole sample that responded to the
>   item is substituted. Person-mean
>   imputation could result in different
>   substitutions for each person with
>   missing items. On the plus side,
>   because it does not substitute a
>   constant value, it does not
>   artificially reduce the measure’s
>   variability and is less likely to
>   attenuate the correlation. A
>   disadvantage is that it tends to
>   inflate the reliability estimates as
>   the number of missing items increases.
>   However, when the numbers of either
>   respondents with missing items or
>   items missing within scales are 20% or
>   less, both item-mean imputation and
>   person-mean imputation provide good
>   estimates of the reliability of
>   measures."

You also might want to check

- Craig K. Enders (2010): [Applied Missing Data Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=MN8ruJd2tvgC&lpg=PA51&ots=dHfCpWZcoa&dq=%22person-mean%20imputation%22&hl=de&pg=PA51#v=onepage&q=%22person-mean%20imputation%22&f=false). (Google books link)
- Downey RG, King C. (1998): [Missing data in Likert ratings: A comparison of replacement methods](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9935342).

Answer (score 4):

Person-mean imputation with an minimum-item threshold is a simple strategy for retaining scale scores where participants miss the occasional response.

#### Some general principles

- If missing data is minimal (e.g., less than 5% of participants are missing 1 item on a 10 item scale), the method of dealing with missing data is unlikely to make a difference to substantive conclusions.
- From a first principle perspective, imputation methods should provide more robust estimates of missing item responses as they incorporate both item and person characteristics into estimating the missing response.
- Design studies to avoid sporadic item-missing data.

#### Conditions where person-mean imputation is more reasonable:

- Item means are all about the same
- The threshold number of missing items is low relative to the total number of items in the scale (e.g., a requirement for 19 out of 20 items is more appropriate than 10 out of 20 items)
- There is generally very little missing data; at the extreme level, there is no missing data, and person-mean imputation does not change the data at all
- the cause of missing data is due to random processes such as accidentally skipping items, not clearly indicating the response, and so on.
- A simple and standardised rule for calculating scale means is desired (e.g., a rule might be required for a test manual that can be applied in a standardised way across studies and samples)

#### Avoiding sporadic missing data for items in scales

At a broader level, person-mean imputation of item responses is a response to a problem that can often be avoided using various study design strategies:

- Computerised administration of questionnaires can prevent (where this is ethically permitted) participants skipping or missing items.
- If questionnaires are administered on paper and in person, the experimenter can review the questionnaire booklet to check for missing data before the participant leaves the room.

Answer (score 1):

one more piece of advice: make sure the full 6-item composite scale is reliable & that none of the included items *reduces* scale reliability. If those conditions aren't satisfied, you shouldn't be averaging them even in cases where data are complete. If these conditions are satisfied, then using a subset of items for cases w/ missing data isn't going to bias your result (assuming you are averaging or adding z-score transformation of items, as you always should in forming aggregate likert scale); it is just going to make it noisier than it should be (b/c you are relying on fewer items & thus cancelling out less of the random measurement error associated with each individual item). 
(Best solution, though, is multiple imputation, again assuming composite scale is reliable.)